# Getting blocked by - ImportError: cannot import name 'cross_validation' from 'sklearn'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to run the code below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

from utilities import visualize_classifier

# Load input data
input_file = 'data_decision_trees.txt'
data = np.loadtxt(input_file, delimiter=',')
X, y = data[:, :-1], data[:, -1]

# Separate input data into two classes based on labels
class_0 = np.array(X[y==0])
class_1 = np.array(X[y==1])

# Visualize input data
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(class_0[:, 0], class_0[:, 1], s=75, facecolors='black', 
        edgecolors='black', linewidth=1, marker='x')
plt.scatter(class_1[:, 0], class_1[:, 1], s=75, facecolors='white', 
        edgecolors='black', linewidth=1, marker='o')
plt.title('Input data')

# Split data into training and testing datasets 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(
        X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=5)

# Decision Trees classifier 
params = {'random_state': 0, 'max_depth': 4}
classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier(**params)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
visualize_classifier(classifier, X_train, y_train, 'Training dataset')

y_test_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
visualize_classifier(classifier, X_test, y_test, 'Test dataset')

# Evaluate classifier performance
class_names = ['Class-0', 'Class-1']
print("\n" + "#"*40)
print("\nClassifier performance on training dataset\n")
print(classification_report(y_train, classifier.predict(X_train), target_names=class_names))
print("#"*40 + "\n")

print("#"*40)
print("\nClassifier performance on test dataset\n")
print(classification_report(y_test, y_test_pred, target_names=class_names))
print("#"*40 + "\n")

plt.show()
```

The error occurs on this line:

```
from sklearn import cross_validation
```

I tried the following, in the Anaconda Command Window:

```
conda update scikit-learn

pip install -U scikit-learn
```

In both cases, I got confirmation stating 'Requirements already up-to-date.'  I'm not sure why I'm getting these error massage when I try to run the script, because everything all the sklearn stuff appears to be up-to-date.  Is there anything else I can try?  This code should definitely work, but it keeps tripping over itself.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your sklearn is up to date, the sklearn.cross_validate module has been deprecated for sklearn.model_selection. Try:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

Comment: I tried "from sklearn import cross_validation" and it printed a DeprecationWarning explaining that it was deprecated in version 0.18 in favour of sklearn.model_selection and would be removed in version 0.20. I assume that my version of sklearn is a little older than yours so it hasn't been removed yet, but in yours it has.